# Django not picking up overridden translation for third-party applications

Tags: django, django-apps, django-i18n

I have a third-party application installed which has translation tags in its templates and also provides translations for those in several languages, but I'd like to change a few translations for only one language.

I ran the `makemessages` command and  the `msgid`'s for those third-party application show up nicely in my own `.po` file in the folder I use as `LOCALE_PATHS`. Then, I added corresponding `msgstr`'s for them, ran `compilemessages` and expected my translations to override the ones that were provided by the third-party application, but I still see the ones provided by the application even though other translations from my own `.po`/`.mo` files *are* correctly showing up.

This procedure *does* work for overriding translations in the Django admin interface (and I'm using the exact same `.po` file for this), so I'm not sure what should be done differently in this case. Is there some setting in the application that could prevent translations being overridden?

I tried everything up to restarting the webserver, rebuilding the Docker images that I'm using, etc. etc., but I only get to see my own translations once I remove the application's `.mo` file, which *does* indicate that my `compilemessages` worked as expected, i.e. adding my translations of the application to my own `.mo` file, but apparently Django is giving preference to the application's `.mo` file instead of mine, despite the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) stating that the language coming from my `LOCALE_PATHS` should have the highest precedence.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it turned out that the `django.po` file supplied by the third-party application was missing a `Plural-Forms` line, whereas the `django.po` file trying to override the translations *did* have this line, which apparently made it impossible for Django to match them together.

After creating a branch of the third-party application in which I created the `django.po`/`django.mo` files *with* the `Plural-Forms` line, I was able to override the default translations without any problems.

Comment: I believe you may accept your solution as the answer. I've seen this done many times, and recommended at least once. (Also, this solution helped me fix my problem. I was missing "Plural-Forms" in my .po file—added it; failing translations worked.)